# Reproducible Random Values in Vector of Arbitrary Length

Tags: r, random, seed

I need to generate a random number corresponding to each value in an index, where it needs to be reproducible for each index value, regardless of how many indexes are given:

As an example, I might provide the indexes 1 to 10, and then in a different time, call the indexes for 5 to 10, and they both need to be the same for the values 5 to 10. Setting a global seed will not do this, it will only keep same for the nth item in the random call by position in the vector.

What I have so far is this, which works as desired:

```
f = function(ix,min=0,max=1,seed=1){
  sapply(ix,function(x){
    set.seed(seed + x)
    runif(1,min,max)
  })
}
identical(f(1:10)[5:10],f(5:10)) #TRUE
identical(f(1:5),f(5:1)) #FALSE
identical(f(1:5),rev(f(5:1))) #TRUE
```

I was wondering if there is a more efficient way of achieving the above, without setting the seed explicitly for each index, as an offset to global seed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `digest` package for tasks like this:

```r
library(digest)
f = function(ix, seed=1){
  sapply(ix, digest, algo = "sha256", seed = seed)
}
identical(f(1:10)[5:10],f(5:10)) #TRUE
#> [1] TRUE
identical(f(1:5),f(5:1)) #FALSE
#> [1] FALSE
identical(f(1:5),rev(f(5:1))) #TRUE
#> [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an encryption.  With a given key, unique inputs will always produce unique outputs.  As long as the numbers you input are distinct then the outputs will always be different; the same numbers will always encrypt to the came output cyphertext.  Use DES for 64 bit numbers or AES for 128 bit numbers.  For other sizes either roll your own Feistel cipher (insecure, but random) or use Hasty Pudding cipher.

Comment: Can you please provide an example?

Comment: An example of what?  Encryption in general?  DES?  AES? A general [Feistel cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feistel_cipher)?  [Hasty Pudding cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasty_Pudding_cipher)?

Comment: An example of how to use this to address my actual question.

Comment: I do not know r, so I cannot give you a working example.  Whenever you want to generate a random-appearing number (it isn't really random of course) from an index, use the r equivalent of `pseudoRandomNumber = encrypt(key, index)`  Keep the key the same, always, and the number generated for each index will be unique and that same index will always generate the same number.